# Isolate common code across generic functions

Tags: c#, architecture

I have two functions in a class. The only differences are the parameter to the function (one taking a Func with a X and the other a Y) and the lines marked with asterisks.

Is there any way to isolate those two lines with asterisks or have a common function, or rewrite the functions such that the try, catch block and last few statements are written only once?

The objective here is to minimize code duplication.

```
public T Do<T>(Func<X, T> something)
{
    try
    {
        var manager = CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param1, Config.Param2); //******
        if (manager != null) return something(manager);
        LoggingHandler.LogWarning(LogTitle, $"manager ({this}) is null.");
    }
    catch (MyException exp)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleRecoverableException(exp, LogTitle,
            $"query on manager ({this}) failed.");
    }

    var msg = $"failed to query using manager ({this})!";
    LoggingHandler.LogCritical(LogTitle, msg);
    throw new MyException(msg);
}


public T Do<T>(Func<Y, T> something)
{
    try
    {
        var manager = CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param3); //******
        if (manager != null) return something(manager);
        LoggingHandler.LogWarning(LogTitle, $"manager ({this}) is null.");
    }
    catch (MyException exp)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleRecoverableException(exp, LogTitle,
            $"query on manager ({this}) failed.");
    }

    var msg = $"failed to query using manager ({this})!";
    LoggingHandler.LogCritical(LogTitle, msg);
    throw new MyException(msg);
}
```

Comment: Are `CoreInfrastructure`, `Prefix` and `Config` accessible outside `Do()` ?

Comment: Prefix and Config are parameters to the Constructor where the Do function reside and stored as private variables. CoreInfrastructure is a static class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create generic method that accepts manager and function

```
    public T Do<T, TManager>(TManager manager, Func<TManager, T> something)
    {
        try
        {
            if (manager != null) return something(manager);
            LoggingHandler.LogWarning(LogTitle, $"manager ({this}) is null.");
        }
        catch (MyException exp)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleRecoverableException(exp, LogTitle,
                $"query on manager ({this}) failed.");
        }

        var msg = $"failed to query using manager ({this})!";
        LoggingHandler.LogCritical(LogTitle, msg);
        throw new MyException(msg);
    }

    public void DoAll<T>(Func<X, T> somethingX, Func<Y, T> somethingY)
    {
        Do(CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param1, Config.Param2), somethingX);
        Do(CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param3), somethingY);
    }
```

As  Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned if creating manager can be source of `MyException` you can add `Func<TManager>` instead of TManager manager:

```
    public T Do<T, TManager>(Func<TManager> managerCreate, Func<TManager, T> something)
    {
        try
        {
            TManager manager = managerCreate();
            if (manager != null) return something(manager);
            LoggingHandler.LogWarning(LogTitle, $"manager ({this}) is null.");
        }
        catch (MyException exp)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleRecoverableException(exp, LogTitle,
                $"query on manager ({this}) failed.");
        }

        var msg = $"failed to query using manager ({this})!";
        LoggingHandler.LogCritical(LogTitle, msg);
        throw new MyException(msg);
    }

    public void DoAll<T>(Func<X, T> somethingX, Func<Y, T> somethingY)
    {
        Do(() => CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param1, Config.Param2), somethingX);
        Do(() => CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param3), somethingY);
    }
```

You can go further and replace `Func<TManager>` with parametrized function where you pass `Prefix` and `Config`

Comment: Whether this is valid depends on whether `GetManager` was the/a source of `MyException`s that `Do` is meant to catch.

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a private function that does the bulk of the work and make the existing methods just wrap it appropriately:

```
private T DoInternal<T>(Func<X> getManager, Func<X, T> something)
{
    try
    {
        var manager = getManager();
        if (manager != null) return something(manager);
        LoggingHandler.LogWarning(LogTitle, $"manager ({this}) is null.");
    }
    catch (MyException exp)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleRecoverableException(exp, LogTitle,
            $"query on manager ({this}) failed.");
    }

    var msg = $"failed to query using manager ({this})!";
    LoggingHandler.LogCritical(LogTitle, msg);
    throw new MyException(msg);
}
public T Do<T>(Func<X, T> something)
{
    return DoInternal(()=> CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param1, Config.Param2), something);
}
public T Do<T>(Func<Y, T> something)
{
    return DoInternal(()=> CoreInfrastructure.GetManager(Prefix, Config.Param3),something);
}
```

Of course, `getManager` may need to be further parameterized if there's common functionality there (e.g. allow `DoInternal` to pass `Prefix`?).

(Also, the above declarations all look a little suspect being only parameterized in `T` and not `X` and `Y`. Some further adjustments may be required there)

Comment: Your's `DoInternal<T>` should have 2 types `DoInternal<T, TManager>` and TManager instead of X in `getManager` and `something`. Otherwise it will work only with `X` and not with `Y`