# Multiple methods with same try/catch logic

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, catch-block

I have a C# program with multiple methods with different parameters and different return types, but most of them have a try/catch block with the same exception logic handling. There are multiple catch statement for all methods, but the logic inside them is the same for all methods.

Is there a way to create a helper method so I won't have duplicate code in the catch ?

```
    public static async Task<long> Method1(string requestedKey)
    {
        try
        {
            //code
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception1 ex)
        {
            Exception1Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception2 ex)
        {
            Exception2Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception3 ex)
        {
            Exception3Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }

        return 0;
    }


    public static async Task<T> Method2(string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            //code
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception1 ex)
        {
            Exception1Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception2 ex)
        {
            Exception2Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception3 ex)
        {
            Exception3Handler(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }

         return default(T);
    }
```

How could I group the catch statements in a helper method, so that I do not have duplicate code?

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be awesome.

Comment: Yes there is. If you would add an example of your code, I am sure someone will take the time to give you an example of how to do it.

Comment: "create a helper method" That´s exactly what you should do. Do you have any problems doing this? What did you try and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes - remove all `try .. catch` blocks.  Handle only exceptions you want to handle, If exceptions can happened because of user's input, do validation instead of throwing exception. Otherwise catch all of them on top layer and provide friendly message to the user.

Comment: `try {method1(); ... methodN();} catch (MyException) {...}`

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I was wrong - rephrased it. My point was don't catch exceptions at all. Only those which you can recover from.

Comment: Does your code look something like the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54037511/15498)? If so, answers there should apply. If not, some concrete examples of what your code *does* look like would help immensely.

Comment: Am I the only one who think the question is pretty clear?

Comment: I also think this is a very clear and valid question. I just voted to reopen it.

Comment: @Fabio I'll give you my use case - in a Blazor app, if something goes wrong in any of the million methods each web page calls, I need to let the user know it didn't work. And literally there are 40 - 60 of these methods across all the web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having this :

```
void AA(string B)
{
    try
    {
        //Do something
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Do something else
    }
}

void AA(string B, string C)
{
    try
    {
        //Do something
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

and type the same exception over and over(I assume they will exactly same since you say so in your question)
you can do something like this :

```
void CallerMethod()
{
    try
    {
        AA("");
        AA("", "");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //My only one exception
    }
}

void AA(string B)
{
    //Do something
}

void AA(string B, string C)
{
    //Do something
}
```

This way if any of your overloaded method will throw an exception you can handle them from only 1 place

Comment: You will still have duplicate ExceptionHandling Code scattered throughout your codebase ...

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is to avoid duplicating catch blocks, you can use the following approach

```
public void HandleException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception1 e)
    {
        // Exception1 handling
    }
    catch (Exception2 e)
    {
        // Exception2 handling
    }
    catch (Exception3 e)
    {
        // Exception3 handling
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Exception handling
    }
}

...

HandleException(() => /* implementation */)
```

Comment: OP's example shows some functions (with async Task/await). But a similar pattern is applicable, I think. I would just add an argument for the Default-Return in case of Exception (see examples).